# Do Poor Code Samples Turn You Away From Libraries?

Tags: frameworks

I've been evaluating a framework that on paper looks great.  The problem is that the sample code is incomplete and of poor quality.  The supplied reference implementations are for the most part not meant to be used (so they can be considered as sample code as well) and have only succeeded at confusing me.

I know that it's common for things to look better on paper, but my experience with the sample code is turning me away from further investigation.

Do you let poor code samples change your judgment of frameworks/libraries? So far my experience has been similar to the "resume effect": if someone doesn't put the effort into spell checking their resume, they probably won't get the job...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poor code samples combined with poor documentation will make me turn away from a library unless there is a compelling reason to use it.  However, a library that has *either* good code samples *or* good documentation is usually worth using.  (Assuming that the library itself otherwise meets my needs.)

Answer (score 3):

For me, it does.  I tend to want to avoid libraries where the code samples are incomplete.  If the library is open source, I will overlook it, since I can directly look at the code and see if the library's internals are reasonable, and I know that, if there is a problem someday, I could (if I had to) fix it.

If the library is commercial, and their samples and/or documentation is poor, I look elsewhere.  I just see it as risk management - poor samples make me fear the quality of the library in general.

No matter how good something is on paper or in theory, it can still be crap when programmed.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a valid reason to turn away from and evaluate other libraries. As a potential user of a library a lack of documentation and/or bad code samples gives the impression that the library is not yet mature enough for use by third parties. In time it may well gain the missing pieces but until then I think its reasonable to look elsewhere.

I was recently evaluating the multitude of blogging applications that people have uploaded to github.com I quickly skipped ones that no documentation as they obviously weren't ready for others to use. The ones that remained at the end had a good README with info on how to get the app up and running as well as an online example of the code running.

Answer (score 2):

If I can't find good examples (and/or documentation) illustrating how to *use* the library, I'm definitely less likely to use it - just as a practical matter, it'll be harder for me to figure out how.  But I don't care what the code that *implements* the library itself looks like. I don't think I'd choose one library/framework over another just because the developers of the one have shown an ability to write cleaner code (which is what I understand the "resume effect" to mean).

Answer (score 2):

Lack of documentation and examples makes me a whole lot less likely to use that particular library.  It's not worth my time testing and trying to figure out how a black box works if there are alternate solutions to the problem out there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely. Every library should come with a simple example using program and a CLI interface (for very simple libraries with `<3` methods and <10 hooks, one example should suffice).

And why does your framework "look great" if it's so hard to use that even the original coders make mistakes using it?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly matters to me. Evidence of sloppy/incomplete coding and poor communication decreases my confidence that the actual implementation code is stable and robust.

Answer (score 0):

Myself yes, but there must be people out there who aren't turned off by this otherwise there are plenty of open source projects that would have died a long long time ago.